# A case-insensitive filter in Clojure / ClojureScript

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I have this function :

```
(defn list-data [alist filter-text]
 (filter (fn [x] (if (nil? filter-text) true
                     (> (.indexOf x filter-text) -1))) alist))

(list-data ["Lion" "Zebra" "Buffalo" "Antelope"] "a")
;=> ("Zebra" "Buffalo")
```

Is there a more idiomatic way of writing this function and respect the fact that I don't want a case-sensitive filter, meaning I would like that `(list-data ["Lion" "Zebra" "Buffalo" "Antelope"] "a")`returns the following:

```
;=> ("Zebra" "Buffalo" "Antelope")
```

Thanks!

(This would need to work in a `.cljs` file)

Comment: Another way to approach this problem is to keep a cache of lowercase values and then use plain `clojure.string/starts-with?`, which might be faster but use more memory.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Clojure itself you would normally do this with a regular expression. In Java regular expressions you can do this by giving in a flag for case-insensitivity for the match you want to make, or at the start of the regex for global case-insensitivity:

```
  (filter #(re-find #"(?i)a" %)
          ["Lion" "Zebra" "Buffalo" "Antelope"])
```

Pure Javascript regular expressions only support global flags. They are given in as string as the second parameter to the regex constructor:

```
  (filter #(re-find (js/RegExp. "a" "i") %)
          ["Lion" "Zebra" "Buffalo" "Antelope"])
```

However, as convenience and to keep the regexes between Java and Javascript similar, the Clojurescript reader translates global java style flags (those at the start of the regex) to their Javascript global equivalent.

So the first example works in Clojurescript as well. Be aware though that non-global flags won't work in Clojurescript where they would work in Clojure.

Comment: Javascript regexes don't support inline modifier flags (ie, `(?i)`).

Comment: From what I read the Clojurescript reader supports Java type inline flags

Comment: I see. https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/master/src/clj/cljs/compiler.clj#L192-L196 takes any inline flags it finds at the beginning of the regex, and uses global flags for them instead. So you can't actually change stuff inline (since it's not supported by javascript), but you can use a syntax that looks like clojure's if you want global flags.

Comment: It works fine with this cljs om example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23179779/how-to-filter-a-list-based-on-user-input-with-clojurescript-and-om Thanks!

Comment: @amalloy Expanded upon the answer now I got to a regular keyboard.

Comment: Time-insensitive URL for the ClojureScript pre-processing snippet that @amalloy linked to: https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/4bbbd60/src/clj/cljs/compiler.clj#L192-L196

Answer (score 4):

```
(defn list-data [alist filter-text]
 (if-let [filter-text (some-> filter-text not-empty .toLowerCase)]
   (filter #(-> % 
                .toLowerCase 
                (.indexOf filter-text)
                (not= -1)) 
           alist)
   alist))
```

Comment: Thanks! Works also fine with this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23179779/how-to-filter-a-list-based-on-user-input-with-clojurescript-and-om Your take is just a little more verbose than @Nielsk's answer.